# How to set specified TimedTextSource as default?

Tags: xaml, uwp, media-player

I'm using `MediaPlayElement`, and I have set the media source.
Now I want to add several `Closed Captions`, such English, Indo, Simplified Chinese.

I use the following code to add TimedTextSource, and they are all placed in the media player, but how to specify an item as turned on when opening a media?

```
var timedTextSource = TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(item.url), item.name);
mediaSource.ExternalTimedTextSources.Add(timedTextSource);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `TimedMetadataTracks.SetPresentationMode` like this:

```cs
// ms: An instance of MediaSource
// mplayer: MediaPlayerElement
// this code is after add the TimedTextSource

var playbackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(ms);
var player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Source = playbackItem;
player.BufferingStarted += (_s, _e) =>
{
    playbackItem.TimedMetadataTracks.SetPresentationMode(0, TimedMetadataTrackPresentationMode.PlatformPresented);
};
mplayer.SetMediaPlayer(player);
```

This method is to actively switch the text track when the video starts to buffer.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, I mean if I want to set English as default on, the code above is not working. The index param of SetPresentationMode set?

Comment: Hi, `Index` is controllable by yourself. If you need English subtitles, adjust to the index of English subtitles. The reason why the `SetPresentationMode` are placed in the `BufferingStarted` event is to make the subtitles fully loaded.